# Cannot umount /tmp. Both fuser and lsof show nothing locking that LV

Tags: 20.04, lvm, umount

I need to reduce my /tmp LV so I type this command :

```bash
$ sudo lvreduce -r -L -2G /dev/myVG/tmp
Do you want to unmount "/tmp" ? [Y|n] y
umount: /tmp: target is busy.
fsadm: Cannot proceed with mounted filesystem "/tmp".
  /sbin/fsadm failed: 1
  Filesystem resize failed.
```

So I investigated with `fuser` and `lsof` but they show nothing :

```bash
$ sudo fuser -vm /tmp
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/tmp:                root     kernel mount /tmp
$ sudo lsof /tmp
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1001/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse file system /run/user/1001/doc
      Output information may be incomplete.
$ sudo lsof +f -- /tmp
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1001/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse file system /run/user/1001/doc
      Output information may be incomplete.
$
```

EDIT0 : I created /tmp manually (and other partitions as well) before installing Ubuntu 20.04 :

```bash
$ mount | grep -w /tmp
/dev/mapper/myVG-tmp on /tmp type ext4 (rw,relatime)
```

EDIT1 : I also tried the same commands in Ubuntu recovery mode but neither `fuser` nor `lsof` were able to show me what process was locking the /tmp filesystem.

The lsof manual is hard to comprehend. Does anyone know if there is another lsof option that can show me more processes that would eventually lock that filesystem ?

Comment: What does `mount | grep tmp` show?  Does it show `tmp` as a `tmpfs`?  THat's not able to be resized with lvreduce because `tmp` is usually in memory, NOT on disk.  Output on my 24.04 system for `/tmp`: `tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noatime,size=10485760k)`

Comment: @ThomasWard See my EDIT0

Comment: OK so you have a unique /tmp setup.  You won't be able to resize `/tmp` while the system is online, the system will have a ton of lockfiles and storage data there.  You'll need to power off the system, boot into an installer or recovery disk, and resize the LV from the other system.  (This is why we usually leave `/tmp/` in `tmpfs`/`memory)

Comment: @ThomasWard OK I see. I also tried the same commands in Ubuntu recovery mode but neither `fuser` nor `lsof` were able to show me what process was locking the /tmp filesystem. The `lsof` manual is hard for me to comprehend. Do you know if there is another `lsof` option that can show me more processes that would eventually lock that filesystem ?

Comment: Recovery mode still mounts `/tmp/`.  I don't know an fuser or lsof that'll list, because there's a lot of things that use `/tmp/` including running SystemD services (core components of SystemD) among other things.  The only way to approach this is to shut down, boot to an installer disk, and then adjust the LVs (so that the `tmp` LV isn't actually being used, since it's not mounted at `/tmp`, and the Kernel and such aren't writing there).

Comment: @ThomasWard OK.Got it. Thanks :+1:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only option here is to power down your system and boot to an alternative environment or LiveUSB.  There's no `lsof` or `fuser` command that'll list that the SystemD system is using `/tmp` for storage of things.

SystemD among other things (critical system processes and such) all write to `/tmp` - this is USUALLY why you don't create LVs or anything for `/tmp` and let it live in volatile memory which is **much much faster** than writing to the disks for temporary files.

The recovery environment also uses `/tmp` because of the kernel and such and critical systemd resources writing there.  This is where you will need to go into your system from the other boot disk, activate the LVM environment, and then resize your LVs from there when there's *no* data being written or used in your special `/tmp` LV.

**I would also recommend that unless your RAM is at a premium, you remove the `/tmp` LV and replace it with a `tmpfs` that lives in RAM and is erased on reboot.** This is why `/tmp` is usually not on-disk but a `tmpfs` in most installs.

Comment: Hi, can you please add your `/tmp` entry from your `/etc/fstab` so I can do something similar ?

Comment: @SebMa sure.  My `/tmp` line also designates the size in memory of the `/tmp` space - on my system I have the RAM to spare so that's up to 10G.  Just set that to the size you want or omit the `size=` part in the options.  This is what's in my `/etc/fstab` for my `/tmp` folder/partition:  `tmpfs   /tmp    tmpfs   defaults,noatime,nosuid,nodev,mode=1777,size=10G    0   0`

Comment: Thanks bro. :+1: